# PayPal Payflow Recurring Billing: re-activating a profile

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, nvp

I would like to re-activate a PayPal recurring billing profile that was cancelled (for reasons that are now moot). The account status is now: `STATUS = DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT`

I can't find what I need online. I have found a lot of reassurances about billing dates. I have also found details of for re-activating the billing profile using methods I am not familiar with.

I use name-value-pairs for these transactions. The data pairs used for the cancellation were:

```
USER=MyId
VENDOR=Business
PARTNER=PayPalCA
PWD=MyPW
TRXTYPE=R
ACTION=C
ORIGPROFILEID=RP0000000XXX
TENDER=C
```

Of course, the `C` value for the `ACTION` name is for "cancel".

Can anyone please tell me the NVP to use for "re-activate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the NVP to use for "re-activate"?

According to the [Payflow Recurring Billing Service User's Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/recurring-billing/#overview-of-recurring-billing-actions-using-the-payflow-sdk), `ACTION=R`

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many webpages I delved through, looking for that link. Thank you.  I understand that it might take a few days for PayPal to complete the reactivation. Is that true? I'm still getting the `DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT` notice on an account inquiry.

Comment: It might take up to a day, or it might be instant, I am not sure. What is the response body to the reactivation?

Comment: No, it is instant. You were right to confirm the response text, which reported an error. I fixed that, and we are good to go. Thank you very much for your help.